# create an ebs micro instance from ami for large one

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-ebs

I have a running large instance (with ephemeral storage), and I need to run several copies on micro instances (with ebs storage) for development / testing purposes. What is the simplest way?

Comment: I think you used the term "AMI" wrong here. AMI is Amazon Machine Image. Of these there are two types, ephemeral and EBS backed. Saying "AMI" does not imply ephemeral, although I suspect that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ec2-bundle-instance` to make an AMI image out of your current system, then launch it

Your question isn't quite clear but it sounds like maybe your current running instances is using an ephemeral root device. In this case you will want to take two steps.

1. First bundle up a new AMI and run it as a new instance so you don't break your running instance.
2. Then follow normal conversion procedures to convert the AMI to an EBS backed instance. Then you should be able to launch it as a micro instance.